# Masking an alpha channel with a gray scale image

Tags: imagemagick

I have been trying to do something with ImageMagick that seems to be a trivial task but I don't get it right.

I have a transparent PNG (32 bit) and I want to mask that one with a grayscale image (also 32 bit). The reason for the files being 32 bits is that they are generated with GIS tools that by default output 32 bits. I would rather not have to change that since all my files have already been generated.

Anyway - this is what I am using now to do this:

```
convert                 \
  alpha_channel.png     \
   \(                   \
      mask.png          \
       -colorspace gray \
       -alpha off       \
   \)                   \
 -compose copy-opacity  \
 -composite             \
  PNG32:output.png
```

The result is almost right but I think there is some problem with the bit depth. It is difficult to explain but you can easily see it by looking at the files and compare "output.png" with "expected_output.png"

Here are the files that I am working with:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/855fh8svgt45mqq/images.zip?dl=0

What do you think I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the output of your `convert -version` command?

Comment: Hi.  I am not at my work station right now to test it but I have the latest Windows binaries installed.  6.9 something I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that all the information is in the alpha channel of the file alpha-channel but you are using the bi-level gray values from that file rather than the actual information which has any content.

```
Image: alpha_channel.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 4096x4096+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Bilevel
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 16777216
    Gray:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 228.324 (0.89539)
      standard deviation: 78.0429 (0.30605)
      kurtosis: 4.67613
      skewness: -2.58382
      mean: 41.3934 (0.162327)
      standard deviation: 22.3399 (0.0876074)
      kurtosis: -0.402954
      skewness: 0.327285
  Alpha: graya(0,0)   #00000000
  Colors: 118
  Histogram:
   1755067: (  0,  0,  0,  0) #00000000 graya(0,0)
    478353: (255,255,255, 37) #FFFFFF25 graya(255,0.145098)
    378182: (255,255,255, 51) #FFFFFF33 graya(255,0.2)
    374922: (255,255,255, 47) #FFFFFF2F graya(255,0.184314)
    368496: (255,255,255, 39) #FFFFFF27 graya(255,0.152941)
    362982: (255,255,255, 49) #FFFFFF31 graya(255,0.192157)
```

And that you are also trying to discard the alpha channel of the file `mask.png` which doesn't seem right either since it has no alpha channel. So, I am confused as to where your information really is, or rather what you actually want to extract. I can only suggest the following which seems to extract what I think you may want but is nothing like what you expect. Still, it may help you get further....

```
convert alpha_channel.png -alpha extract \
   \( mask.png -colorspace gray \) \
   -compose copy-opacity -composite out.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  You have exposed my ignorance when it comes to ImageMagick   :) I wasn't really sure what my command was doing but after a long Google session it looked like it would do what I wanted - but clearly didn't.  It seems like I didn't explain the end result required very well so let me try to do that here...

Comment: The resulting image is to be used in Unity3D for a displacement shader. For technical reasons the image can not simply be a grayscale image - it has to have transparency - as alpha_channel.png does and it works fine.  What I need additionally is to mask it with mask.png while preserving transparency.  Is that more clear?  You could open expected_output.png to see the required result.  I created that image in photoshop by using mask.png as a layer mask on alpha_channel.png.

Comment: Mmm, I can't see what you have done at all!!! I open alpha_channel in Photoshop and added mask as a mask and it doesn't look the same as your expected output. I then overlaid your expected output on top and selected `difference` blending mode which should be black if there are no differences but the differences were enormous. Did you take some other steps in Photoshop?

Comment: Here is my Photoshop file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9itw0fonstt1ajq/expected_output.psd?dl=0
I did also notice the difference when I tried to overlay it with the expected_output.png as you did.  I think that ist because of compression or something.

Comment: I have found a decent solution although it is a two step process.  I think it could be done in one step though.

`convert mask.png -background Red -negate -alpha shape mask_shape.png`

`convert alpha_channel.png mask_shape.png -compose DstOut -composite output.png`
Maybe you can see from this two step process what I am trying to make.

Comment: This is a one-liner... convert alpha_channel.png \\( mask.png -background Red -negate -alpha shape \\) -compose DstOut -composite output.png